# getbalance and listaddressgroupings inconsistent

Tags: bitcoind, electrum, testnet, balance, private-key-import

I imported a private key from my electrum wallet (testnet) to bitcoincore (testnet) as follow:

1. In my electrum wallet, I copy the private key associated to the address [mmUToPM2vBb2F1ZNcR86J12GxqAbUJtFCr](https://www.blockchain.com/en/btctest/address/mmUToPM2vBb2F1ZNcR86J12GxqAbUJtFCr) (balance of 0.06 BTC)
2. Then I import it into bitcoincore:

`~# bitcoin-cli importprivkey "the 52 characters private key here" "From Electrum Wallet"`

3. Rescan should be automatic but I ask for a reindex and rescan:

`~# bitcoind -rescan -reindex`

After a while, I can issue:

`~# bitcoin-cli listaddressgroupings`

And I successfully get:

```
[
 [
   [
     "mmUToPM2vBb2F1ZNcR86J12GxqAbUJtFCr",
     0.06000000,
     "From Electrum Wallet"
   ]
 ],
 [
   [
     "2MwBERpNv7JJaW4nVUbQncXjFjG1nFKLYEp",
     0.05000000,
     "test"
   ],
   [
     "2N4AMdXitdYhNdjafzHG61uUdrErExSdhKs",
     0.00498305
   ]
 ],
 [
   [
     "2N6xTkaeuKsQSHCortgxiNvsVXj2Gv1Qy85",
     0.05000000,
     "test2"
   ]
 ]
]
```

But when I ask for the balance, it returns 0:

`~# bitcoin-cli getbalance mmUToPM2vBb2F1ZNcR86J12GxqAbUJtFCr`

`0.00000000`

How possible is that, considering that the rescan has been performed and that the balance is correct in listaddressgroupings? As a result, I am not able to spend bitcoins from this address.

Thank you for you input/insight!

My bitcoin.conf:

```
txindex=1
addrindex=1
listen=1
server=1
daemon=1
testnet=1
```

Comment: There is no addrindex=1 setting in Bitcoin Core, so what software are you asking about?   What does the listunspent output show?

Comment: I used [addrindex](https://counterpartytalk.org/t/what-is-addrindex-and-why-is-it-necessary/1202) as I was desperate. My listunspent show the two unspent transactions as expected, both are marked spendable, solvable and safe. Output [here](https://gitlab.univ-lorraine.fr/dufour18/cert-bundle/snippets/7).

Comment: I use bitcoincore 0.16.3 built from [source](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin).

Answer (score 1):

You are using `getbalance` incorrectly. You have specified an account name of the address that you want the balance for. However this is not how `getbalance` works. Bitcoin does not use accounts and addresses are not accounts. An account here means an account in Bitcoin Core's internal accounts system which has since been removed.

So your command `getbalance mmUToPM2vBb2F1ZNcR86J12GxqAbUJtFCr` is asking for the balance of the account named `mmUToPM2vBb2F1ZNcR86J12GxqAbUJtFCr`, but no such account exists. The account that has the address `mmUToPM2vBb2F1ZNcR86J12GxqAbUJtFCr` is named `From Electrum Wallet`. Thus the command you should be using is

```
getbalance "From Electrum Wallet"
```